# Recursive method implementation problem with Spark

Tags: java, algorithm, apache-spark, graph

I have a graph with nodes to color, where for each node a dataset (a collection of rows / tuples) is associated.

The algorithm is explained by this example:

[image: Graph coloring problem]

> the uploaded figure shows an execution of Coloring over graph G with
> nodes {v1, v3, v2}. Figure (a) initializes nodes as
> uncolored. We first consider v1, and select Sσ1 = {{t9, t10}} (Figure (b)). We color nodes v2 and v3 by recursively calling Coloring.
>
> Coloring one node may restrict the color choice of neighboring nodes,
> e.g. after we select {{t9, t10}} for v1, we cannot select {{t6, t7,
> t10}} for v3 due to the overlapping tuple t10. For node v3,
>
> we have several choices including {{t6, t7}} and {{t7, t8}}. In Figure (c), we assume the coloring algorithm chooses {{t6, t7}} for
> v3. As a result, {{t5, t6}}, which was the only choice forv2, cannot
> be used due to the overlapping tuple t6. This leads the algorithm
> towards an unsatisfying clustering (Figure (d)). The algorithm
> backtracks its last decision for v3 by selecting a different color,
> {{t7, t8}} for v3 in Figure (e). In this case, the clustering {{t5,
> t6}} for v2 does not overlap with {{t7, t8}}. Since we have found a
> clustering that satisfies all the constraints (i.e., a coloring of all nodes), Coloring returns true with V containing the nodes and their colors
> (i.e., clusterings).

Here's my code i am trying (which i suspect it is wrong the way it colors the nodes because the algorithm runs for too long )
`nodeIterator` parameter contains all nodes of the graph sorted in customized way.

```
 public Boolean coloring(graph, nodeIterator, vector){

            Node  nodeIt  ;
            if (nodeIterator.hasNext())
                nodeIt = nodeIterator.next();
    
            else {
                return false;
            }
    
            // cluster is the current node associated  dataset
            ArrayList<Dataset<Row>> cluster = allClustersOfGraph.getNextDataset(nodeIt.name);

    
    
            if (graph.getNeighbors(nodeIt) == null) {
               
                if (!nodeIterator.hasNext()){
                    colorNode(vector, nodeIt);
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    colorNode(vector, nodeIt);
                    nodeIterator.next();
                }
            }
            Iterable<Node> adjNodes = graph.getNeighbors(nodeIt);
            Iterator<Node> adjNodesIt = adjNodes.iterator();
            // i suspect in the line under, while is an if so that next neighboring nodes of the current processed one, will be in turn processed in the next recursive call of this algorithm
            while (adjNodesIt.hasNext()){
    
                Node adjNode = adjNodesIt.next();
                if (!checkNodeColored(vector, adjNode)) {
                    ArrayList<Dataset<Row>> adjCluster = allClustersOfGraph.getNextDataset(adjNode.name);
    
                    for (Dataset<Row> subCluster : cluster) {
    
    
                        for (Dataset<Row> subAdjCluster : adjCluster) {
    
                            // small datasets (tuples of rows) don't intersect
                            if (noDatasetIntersection(subCluster, subAdjCluster)) {
    
    
                                 colorNode(vector, nodeIt, subCluster);
    
    
                                if (coloring(graph, nodeIterator, vector)) {
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                   // vector is where current coloring progress is maintained
                                    // move backwards
                                    vector.remove(vector.size() - 1);
    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (!adjNodesIt.hasNext()) {
    
                    
    
                            // Color last node anyway
    
                            colorNode(vector, nodeIt);
    
                    
                    return true;
                }
    
            }
    
            return false;
    }
```

`allClustersOfGraph` is of type `ArrayList<ArrayList<Dataset<Row>>>`
Here's also the pseudo-algorithm :

[image: coloring pseudo-algo]

***My question is :*** i created the loop `while (adjNodesIt.hasNext()){...`in my code to check for one recursive call all neighboring nodes of the current processed node, is it right to do that in a recursive method ? Also are all limit cases treated through my implementation ?
Thanks for the great help!

Comment: The loop `for (Dataset<Row> ss : cluster) { colorNode(vector, nodeIt); }` looks strange. It colors the same node potentially many times. Is it intended? If so, does it have a side effect on the `vector`?

Comment: i removed it in my new code yesterday and only kept the colorNode call (to color last node of the graph) !